# Issues getting web.config to work properly

Tags: html, iis, web

I am having some issues getting my webconfig to work properly. It is redirecting all files, it should only redirect files/urls that don't exist as a file on the system. I am running IIS web server. I started out with the below .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteLog "mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and this is my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule 1q" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true"     />
    </rule>
         </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension="js" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension="css" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have no clue how to make it only redirect files/urls that don't exist as a file on the system. Any ideas?

EDIT I FIXED IT

need to add conditions to the file to check if it's a file

```
<conditions> 
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

entire web.config looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule 1q" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions> 
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true"    />
    </rule>
         </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension="js" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension="css" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and reference this site for more information:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_pattern_syntax

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [webmasters.se]
